# How does return statement work in switch?

Tags: ios, swift, recursion, switch-statement, return

The code below creates a calculator which remembers all the operands and the operators.The "Evaluate" function takes an array of Ops and returns a tuple with the result and the remaining operations.But I am having trouble understanding what's up with switch.

If the case is that opStack has 4,x,5,+,6  The last element 6 is removed and checked for,in the switch .Since it is an operand it will return 6 (operand)and the rest of the elements 4,x,5,+.

Is my understanding correct? Where do the "6" and "4,x,5,+" go and how will the entire expression be evaluated?

```
         private enum Op {
    case Operand (Double)
    case UnaryOperation(String , Double -> Double)
    case BinaryOperation(String , (Double,Double) -> Double)
        }
private var opStack = [Op]()
private var knownOps = [String : Op]()

init() {
    knownOps["×"] = Op.BinaryOperation("×" , *)
    knownOps["÷"] = Op.BinaryOperation("÷" ){ $1 / $0 }
    knownOps["+"] = Op.BinaryOperation("+" , +)
    knownOps["−"] = Op.BinaryOperation("−" ){ $1 - $0 }
    knownOps["√"] = Op.UnaryOperation("√" ,sqrt)
}

   private func evaluate( ops : [Op]) -> (result : Double? , remainingOps: [Op]){

    if !ops.isEmpty {
        var remainingOps = ops
        let op = remainingOps.removeLast()

        switch op{

        case .Operand(let operand):
            return (operand , remainingOps)

        case .UnaryOperation( _ , let operation):
            let operandEvaluation = evaluate(remainingOps)
         if let operand = operandEvaluation.result{
            return ( operation(operand), operandEvaluation.remainingOps) }

}
        case .BinaryOperation(_, let operation):
            let op1Evaluation = evaluate(remainingOps)
            if let operand1 = op1Evaluation.result {
                let op2Evaluation = evaluate(op1Evaluation.remainingOps)
                if let operand2 = op2Evaluation.result {
                    return (operation(operand1, operand2), op2Evaluation.remainingOps)
                }
            }
        }
          }
    return(nil , ops)
}
```

Comment: The function is recursive; note that the `UnaryOperation` and `BinaryOperation` cases call `evaluate`.  You can set a breakpoint and single step through the function to see how it works, but I suspect you are incorrect when you say that the operand stack has `4,x,5,+,6` in it.  It looks like it would have two operations "4x5" and "+6"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah you are doing the Stanford swift lectures! They are great. I had some issue with this function as well back when I was going through them.

Basically the calculator is quite atypical in how it works, it takes a little while to use it properly as a user. The call stack would return 6 in this case you are absolutely right. Then the user could evaluate again, however your call stack wouldn't work properly.

The calculator expects this flow for a binary operation:

User inputs operand1 and adds it to the stack
User inputs operand2 and adds it to the stack. 
THEN the user inputs the binary operator they would like to apply to the operands

So a call stack for a binary operation looks like this:

[5,6,*]

Which would evaluate to 30

For a unary operation it expects:

User inputs operand and adds it to the stack
User chooses unary operation they would like to apply to the operand

So a unary call stack looks like:

[4,√]

Which would evaluate to 2

It works this way, where an operand without a operation preceding it in the stack would end the evaluate run, because otherwise it wouldn't understand the rest of the stack (look at your stack and compare it to what the calculator expects and you will see what I mean)

Also like @paulw11 I would highly recommend setting a breakpoint at the beginning of evaluate and running it through it step by step (very slowly) as getting your head around how it works is extremely useful.

Comment: Thanks , this helped. y)